# Solving for X in XAX = 0 where X is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an (unknown) idempotent matrix $X$ which is diagonal, and all diagonal entries are either 0 or 1. (Thus, $X = X^{n}$ for all n > 0) How can I solve for $X$ in $XAX = 0$ where $X$ and $A$ are $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A$ is known (real-valued) and **not symmetric**, **not invertible**.

I know that there is guaranteed to be at least one solution (ignoring the trivial solution $X=0$), and probably multiple. Ideally I want the solution with the largest trace (most 1's on the diagonal).

My first intuition was, let $x$ be a vector using the diagonal of $X$, then solve $x^{T}A = 0 = Ax$, which would work for all vectors $v$ in either the left or right null-space of $A$. Then the solution I want is some linear combination of these vectors. But how to find a solution with all values being 0 or 1, and also maximizing the trace?

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be idempotent or do you want $X$ to be idempotent and diagonal (w.r.t. the standard basis(?), hence diagonal)? 
Since $\text{tr}(X)=\text{rank}(X)$ for $X$ idempotent, you are looking for non-zero eigenvectors of $X$ to the eigenvalue $1$. But in order to get $XAX=0$ these eigenvectors also have to be in $\text{ker}(A)$, which is the eigenspace to the eigenvalue $0$. 
By saying that $X$ is diagonal, you are a priori fixing the eigenbasis for $X$.

Comment: I want $X$ to be idempotent and diagonal. I know for sure it is solvable, because I have an instance of the problem where $X, A \in \mathbb{R}^{145\times 145}$ and rank($X$) = 68, rank($A$) = 114

Comment: Just to be sure: are you looking for a general solution or do you have a certain problem with a given matrix $A$ for which you need to find such an $X$?
Because in the general case you will not always find nontrivial $X$. For instance if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ the only solution to $XAX=0$ is $X=0$ (= zero matrix), if $X$ is required to be diagonal.

Comment: Without going too much into it, I am looking for a general solution BUT I can safely assume there always exists a non-trivial solution for X. The reason I can make this assumption is that at the moment, I have perfect knowledge of the problem (I know a valid X for any given A). In practice I will not know X, but there will most certainly be a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Your $XAX$ will be diagonal, and its diagonal entries will be diagonal entries of $A$ or $0$.  (I mean, $(XAX)_{i,i}=a_{i,i}$ or $0$, for each $i$.) See if you can figure out the connection between $X$ and the precise values of the diagonal entries of $XAX$.

Comment: Not sure I follow that, since $XAX = 0$ then all $(XAX)_{i,i} = 0$ right?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is deceptive, and contains an hidden surprise.

Suppose  $X$ is diagonal and all its diagonal entries $x_{i,i}$ are equal to $0$ or $1$.  Let $C$ be the set of $i$ such that $x_{i,i}=1$.  Then $XAX$ is $A$ with all entries occurring in   rows  $i$ and all entries  in columns $i$, for $i\notin C$, being replaced by $0$:
$$(XAX)_{i,j}=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if } i\notin C \text{ or } j\notin C\\a_{i,j}&\text{ if } i\in C\text{ and } u\in C.\end{cases}$$

Now consider the graph $G$ with vertex set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and with an edge connecting $i$ and $j$ whenever $a_{i,j}\ne0$.  The requirement that $XAX=0$ translates into the clique with vertex set $C$ being a subgraph of $G$, and the problem of finding the $X$ of maximal trace is that of finding the largest clique in $G$. This is a well-known hard problem in computational graph theory; see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) for details.
The executive summary: unless you only care about small matrices you are doomed to using approximate and/or expensive solution methods

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Here's a counterexample: $$XAX = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 0 & 5 \\
6 & 7 & 0
\end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 7 & 0
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Comment: I have completely rewritten my answer.  You are quite correct with your counterexample, and your problem is much harder than I had thought.